# moving a sprite with a function in pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

i am spawning in an enemy using the spawn() class, and in the spawn(0 class, i am trying to use the function move() to move the enemy. when i run the program, the zombie spawns, but doesnt move.

Below is the entire code if anybody was wondering. I am only having problems with the spawn() class and nothing else.

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
#################################################################################

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
grey = (125,125,125)

#################################################################################
leng = 1200
wid = 600
FPS = 60
size = 30

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont('calibri',20)

def message(msg,colour,loc):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, colour)
    screen.blit(screen_text, loc)

def rot_center(image, angle):
    orig_rect = image.get_rect()
    rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
    rot_rect.center = rot_image.get_rect().center
    rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
    return rot_image


def quit():
    pygame.quit()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((leng,wid),0,32)
background = pygame.image.load("background.png")
################################################################################
def gameLoop():

    class spawn:

        def __init__(self,x,y, px,py,angle):

            self.x=x

            self.y=y

            self.px = px

            self.py = py

            self.angle = angle

            self.i = pygame.image.load("zombie.png")

            self.i2 = rot_center(self.i, self.angle)

            if self.x > self.px:
                self.x -= 2 
            if self.x < self.px:
                self.x += 2 

            if self.y > self.py:
                self.y -= 2 
            if self.y < self.py:
                self.y += 2 


        def render(self):

            screen.blit(self.i2, (self.x,self.y))

    x = leng/2
    y = wid/2

    player = pygame.image.load("player.png")

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    spr = 50
    spr_change = 0

    u = 2
    spru = u*1.5
    zu = u

    cursor = pygame.image.load("cursor.gif") 
    mouseX = 0
    mouseY = 0
    mouse_click = 0
    mouse_rev = 0
    mm = 0
    mr = 0

    points = 0
    accuracy = 0
    shots = 0
    kills = 0
    health = 10

    boost = pygame.image.load("boost.png")
    boost_x = random.randint(0, leng-20)
    boost_y = random.randint(0, wid-20)

    gun = pygame.image.load("gun.png")
    bullet = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
    bullet_x = random.randint(0, leng-20)
    bullet_y = random.randint(0, wid-20)
    ammo = 12

    zombie = pygame.image.load("zombie.png")
    zombie_x = random.randint(0,leng-30)
    zombie_y = random.randint(0,wid-30)
    z_angle = 0
    z_rect = 0
################################################################################
    apple = pygame.image.load("cubeberry.png")
    apple_x = random.randint(0, leng-20)
    apple_y = random.randint(0, wid-20)
##################################################################################    
    while True:

        mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouse_click, mm, mr = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(mouseX-x, mouseY-y))+90
        z_angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(x-zombie_x, y-zombie_y))+90

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and spr > 0:
                        u = spru
                        spr_change -= 1
                    x_change = -u
                    #y_change = 0
                    if x < 0:
                        x_change = u

                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and spr > 0:
                        u = spru
                        spr_change -= 1
                    x_change = u
                    #y_change = 0
                    if x > leng- size:
                        x_change = -u

                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and spr > 0:
                        u = spru
                        spr_change -= 1
                    y_change = -u
                    #x_change = 0
                    if y < 0:
                        y_change = u

                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and spr > 0:
                        u = spru
                        spr_change -= 1
                    y_change = u
                    #x_change = 0
                    if y > wid - size:
                        y_change = -u

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and spr > 0:
                    u = spru
                    spr_change -= 1

                if event.key == pygame.K_a and event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    if x < 0 and y < 0:
                        x_change = u
                        y_change = u

                if event.key == pygame.K_a and event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    if x < 0 and y > wid - size:
                        x_change = u
                        y_change = -u

                if event.key == pygame.K_d and event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    if x > leng-size and y < 0:
                        x_change = -u
                        y_change = u

                if event.key == pygame.K_d and event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    if x > leng-size and y > wid-size:
                        x_change = -u
                        y_change = -u


            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    x_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    x_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    y_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    y_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    u = spru/2
                    spr_change = 0
##########################################################################################
        if spr <= 0 :
            spr_change = 0

        if x < 0:
            x_change = u
            x += x_change
            x_change = 0

        if x > leng-size:
            x_change = -u
            x += x_change
            x_change = 0

        if y < 0:
            y_change = u
            y += y_change
            y_change = 0

        if y > wid-size:
            y_change = -u
            y += y_change
            y_change = 0

        x += x_change
        y += y_change
        spr += spr_change
#############################################################################
        if apple_x <= x <= apple_x + size and apple_y <= y <= apple_y + size:
            apple_x = random.randint(0, leng-20)
            apple_y = random.randint(0, wid-20)
            points += 100
            health += 2

        if x <= apple_x <= x + size and y <= apple_y <= y + size:
            apple_x = random.randint(0, leng-20)
            apple_y = random.randint(0, wid-20)
            points += 100
            health += 2
################################################################################
        if bullet_x <= x <= bullet_x + size and bullet_y <= y <= bullet_y + size:
            bullet_x = random.randint(0, leng-20)
            bullet_y = random.randint(0, wid-20)
            points += 50
            ammo += 4

        if x <= bullet_x <= x + size and y <= bullet_y <= y + size:
            bullet_x = random.randint(0, leng-20)
            bullet_y = random.randint(0, wid-20)
            points += 50
            ammo += 4
##################################################################################          
        if mouse_click == 1 and ammo >0 and mouse_rev == 0:
            ammo -= 1
            shots += 1
            mouse_rev = 1

        if mouse_click == 0:
            mouse_rev = 0

        if mouse_rev == 1 and zombie_x <= mouseX <= zombie_x + size and zombie_y <= mouseY <= zombie_y+ size and ammo >=0:
            zombie_x = random.randint(0, leng-20)
            zombie_y = random.randint(0, wid-20)
            mouse_rev = 1
            kills += 1
            points += 250

###################################################################################
        if boost_x <= x <= boost_x + size and boost_y <= y <= boost_y + size:
            boost_x = random.randint(0, leng-20)
            boost_y = random.randint(0, wid-20)
            points += 50
            spr += 20

        if x <= boost_x <= x + size and y <= boost_y <= y + size:
            boost_x = random.randint(0, leng-20)
            boost_y = random.randint(0, wid-20)
            points += 50
            spr += 20
################################################################################

        if x <= zombie_x <= x + size and y <= zombie_y <= y + size:
            points -= 5
            health -= 0.1

        if zombie_x <= x <= zombie_x + size and zombie_y <= y <= zombie_y + size:
            points -= 5
            health -= 0.1

        if not shots == 0:
            accuracy = 100 * float(kills)/float(shots)
        else:
            accuracy = 0
###################################################################################            
        #player = pygame.image.load("player.png")
        rect_player = rot_center(player, angle)
        gun = pygame.image.load("gun.png")
        gun = pygame.transform.rotate(gun, angle)
        #zombie = pygame.image.load("zombie.png")
        #z_rect = rot_center(zombie, z_angle)

        z1 = spawn(zombie_x, zombie_y,x,y,z_angle)
##################################################################################

        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(background,(leng,wid)),(0,0))
        #pygame.display.flip()
        screen.blit(apple, (apple_x,apple_y))
        screen.blit(rect_player, (x,y))
        screen.blit(gun, (x+10,y))
        screen.blit(boost, (boost_x,boost_y))
        #screen.blit(z_rect, (zombie_x,zombie_y))
        z1.render()
        screen.blit(bullet, (bullet_x,bullet_y))
        screen.blit(cursor, (mouseX -42.5, mouseY - 42.5))
        message("Points: "+str(points), red, [0,0])
        message("Ammo: " +str(ammo), black, [0,20])
        message("Sprint: " +str(spr), blue, [0,40])
        message("Accuracy: " +str(int(accuracy)), red, [0, 60])
        message("Health: " + str(int(health)), blue,[0,80])
        #pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)



gameLoop()
```

Comment: where is the entire code?

Comment: @ QIstudio see above

Comment: Make sure you're code in the question is correct. Currently, your code have several syntax errors and cannot be tested.

Comment: @Ted Klein Bergman i edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was very hard to read and you should consider the following:

### Divide your code in functions

As of right now, you have one function that contains almost 300 lines of code. Try divide up the code in small functions that does one thing only. Your first two functions are great! Maybe your event loop could go into one function and the rendering to another and so on.

Not only are small functions easier to read, but they're very useful when you need to repeat similar code to what you've already written. If you have code that looks similar just put what's identical inside the body of the function and what differs as parameters to the function.

### Use descriptive names

I've been looking at your code for over an hour and still don't know what *spr*, *spru*, *u*, *zu*, *mm* or *mr* means or what they're used for. Try using names that better describe what the variables are to make it easier for others to read your code. For example, *length* and *width* are better names then *leng* and *wid* because they say what they are. Don't try to shortened already short words!

Also, make sure to start a name of a class with a capital letter. This helps programmers to identify what's a class and what's a function. So name your *spawn* to *Spawn* instead.

Follow the [conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions) to make it easier for other people to understand your code and better help you. Not only the naming conventions, but also things like putting space around operators etc.

### Try using classes

Classes are like a collection of variables. This could be very useful to have instead of creating 4-5 variables that are related separately, and also makes it possible to reuse code! You're probably going to need classes if you want to create more zombies or apples, and it could improve readability.

### To answer your question

Right now you're code doesn't work because you don't have any method or function in your code named *move*. The error before your edit was a syntax error because you defined your parameters wrong. To fix the class and make it work with the rest of your code would require much of the other code to be changed. To be completely honest, I think all of your code needs to be rewritten to be able to do much more with your game.

Try learn more about functions, loops and classes. I'm sorry but I believe you need more knowledge about these to progress any further.

Comment: Thanks! im new to pygame and this was just and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `return zombie_x , zombie_y as self.x, self.y` why are you not writing this? `self.x,self.y = zombie_x,zombie_y`

Edit: As mentioned by ninMonkey, `move` is not a function of class `spawn`. Put it in the class and it should work.

Comment: `move` should be a function of `spawn`. Right now it's alone with no reference to `self` which gives the error.